# M.2 drive with 200,000 IOps R/W

Tags: ssd, data-storage

Recently, I've been eye-ing the [PNY CS2030](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M08ERD1), and it has quite the specs to share. According to the specs, it boasts 201kIOps Read, and 215kIOps write. Additionally, it says a read speed 2.75 GB/s and write of 1.5GB/s.

I'm looking for close comparing competitors. Specifically, under the following qualifications:

- Under 150 USD
- 220 GB or more capacity
- 150k IOps in read and write or more
- At least 2GB/s read
- At least 1GB/s write
- M.2 Form Factor
- available in the US (but it doesn't have to be exclusive)

Bonus if it beast out the PNY in some aspects for its price.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PNY SSD is pretty good, but looks like I can just barely beat you out ;)

### SAMSUNG 960 EVO M.2 250GB

[$128 @ newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16820147593) ships free in the US

- 250 GB
- 300,000 IOPS 4K Random Write
- 330,000 IOPS 4K Random Read
- 3.2 GB/s read
- 1.5 GB/s write
- M.2 Sata NVMe PCIe
  [image]

I've had great sucess with Samsung SSD products. The cheaper Samsung evo Sata (non M.2 and slower as a result) SSDs are also a great upgrade to older computers. I personally own a 940 evo and stand by it.